# JMockit - expectation returns old value instead of value associated with private field

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, jmockit

When recording an expectation that returns the value of a field, I would expect the returned value to be the value of the field when the actual method was invoked (value of the reference), as opposed to the field's value when the expectation was recorded.

This is the class under test (actually 2 of them):

```
public class ListObservingCache<T> extends ObservingCache {
public ListObservingCache(Supplier<List<T>> syncFunc, int intervalMillis) {
    super(syncFunc, intervalMillis);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public List<T> getItems() {     
    return items != null ? Collections.unmodifiableList((List<T>) items) : null;
}
}



public abstract class ObservingCache {
private static final int DEFAULT_CACHE_REFRESH_INTERVAL = 10 * 60 * 1000; // 10 minutes
private static int DEFAULT_CACHE_INITIAL_DELAY = 10 * 60 * 1000; // 10 minutes
private static final int DEFAULT_THREAD_POOL_SIZE = 5;

private static ScheduledExecutorService executor;

protected Object items;

protected ObservingCache(Supplier<? extends Object> syncFunc) {
    this(syncFunc, DEFAULT_CACHE_REFRESH_INTERVAL);
}

protected ObservingCache(Supplier<? extends Object> syncFunc, int intervalMillis) {
    if (executor == null || executor.isShutdown()) {
        executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(DEFAULT_THREAD_POOL_SIZE);
    }
    Runnable task = () -> {
        Object result = syncFunc.get();
        if (result != null) {
            items = result;
        }
    };
    task.run(); // First run is blocking (saves a lot of trouble later).
    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, DEFAULT_CACHE_INITIAL_DELAY, intervalMillis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}

public abstract Object getItems();

}
```

Here is my test class:

```
public class ListObservingCacheTest {
List<Integer> provList; // <-- The field I wish to use instead of the "willReturnList()" method

@Mocked
DummyTask mockTask;

@BeforeClass
public static void setupClass() {
    ObservingCache.DEFAULT_CACHE_INITIAL_DELAY = 100;
}

@AfterClass
public static void tearDownClass() {
    ExecutorService toShutDown = (ExecutorService) getField(ObservingCache.class, "executor");
    toShutDown.shutdown();
}

@Before
public void setUp() {
    mockTask = new DummyTask(); // Empty list
}

@Test
public void testBasic() throws Exception {
    willReturnList(Arrays.asList(1, 2));
    ListObservingCache<Integer> obsCache = new ListObservingCache<Integer>(() -> mockTask.acquireList(), 300);
    assertEquals(Arrays.asList(1, 2), obsCache.getItems());
    willReturnList(Arrays.asList(3, 4, 5));
    assertEquals(Arrays.asList(1, 2), obsCache.getItems()); // ObservingCache should still returns the former list because its interval hasn't passed yet
    Thread.sleep(300);
    assertEquals(Arrays.asList(3, 4, 5), obsCache.getItems()); // ObservingCache should now return the "new" list, as its interval has passed and the task has been executed again
}

/**
 * Instructs the mock task to return the specified list when its
 * acquireList() method is called
 */
private void willReturnList(List<Integer> list) {
    new Expectations() {{ mockTask.acquireList(); result = list; }};
}

/**
 * Simulates an ObservingCache "real-life" task. Should never really be
 * called (because it's mocked).
 */
class DummyTask {
    private List<Integer> list;

    public List<Integer> acquireList() {
        return list;
    }
}
```

}

This test passes, but I would like a more elegant way to set the expectation for the return value of the `acquireList()` method, as this kind of "willReturn" methods would become a maintenance nightmare once I have more than one of these in the same class.

I'm looking for something similar to the mockito-syntax command:

```
when(mockTask.acquireList()).thenReturn(provList);
```

This should always return the **current** value of the provList field (as opposed to its value when the expectation was recorded).

**EDIT:**
After going through the documentation, I came up with a solution, using  delegates:

```
new Expectations() {{
                mockTask.acquireList();
                result = new Delegate<List<Integer>>() {
                    List<Integer> delegate() {
                        return provList; // The private field
                    }
                };
            }};
```

There are 2 problems with this approach:
1. It's not elegant
2. The `List<Integer> delegate()` method causes a compile-time warning:

> The method delegate() from the type new Delegate>(){} is never
>   used locally

Therefore, still looking for another solution

Comment: You should describe the actual problem you want to solve, rather than describing a solution. The example test is not helpful, since all it does is testing the mock itself.

Comment: I did describe the problem - I need to find an elegant/efficient way to make the test pass. The 3 solutions proposed are supposed to give a direction to whoever attempts to answer. Same goes for the example test. I'm aware of the fact that it tests the mock. I wrote it like that in order to present the problem in the simplest way possible.

Comment: As it currently stands, the question doesn't even make sense, if you think about it. How would a test know *when* to set a mutable field, such that each call from the mocked method returns with the desired value of the field? I just can't see how a real-world test would use such a feature, assuming that a mocking API could support it.

Comment: The mocking API (that you seemingly wrote) does support it, through delegates, as I described in my question. My made up test is a simpler version of a real test that I needed to write for a real world application. I would've specified the real requirement if I thought that it was necessary.

Comment: Sure, using a `Delegate` allows the test to return the current value of the field, but who sets the field to the next value, and when? That's the part I don't get, and which can only become clear once the actual problem to be solved is described.

Comment: Edited according to your comments. Added the real test. Hope it's clearer now. 10x

Comment: Um...`The method delegate() from the type new Delegate>(){} is never used locally` is not a compile time exception. Actually it's not an exception at all; it's a warning. This tells me your compiler is set up to treat warnings as exceptions. So it's not a problem with the code, it's that your compiler is setup to fail on minute problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem the OP is trying to "solve" is this: how to simplify the writing of multiple tests in a single test method, when the code under test (here, the `obsCache.getItems()` method) and the verifications to perform are the same, but the input values are different.

So, this is really a question about how to properly write tests. The basic form of a well-written test is described by the ["Arrange-Act-Assert" (AAA)](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ArrangeActAssert) pattern:

```
@Test
public void exampleOfAAATest() {
    // Arrange: set local variables/fields with input values, 
    // create objects and/or mocks, record expectations.

    // Act: call the code to be tested; normally, this is *one* method
    // call only.

    // Assert: perform a number of assertions on the output, and/or
    // verify expectations on mocks.
}

@Test
public void exampleOfWhatisNotAnAAATest() {
    // First "test":
    // Arrange 1
    // Act
    // Assert 1

    // Second "test":
    // Arrange 2 (with different inputs)
    // Act again
    // Assert 2

    // ...
}
```

Obviously, tests like the second one above are regarded as bad practice, and should not be encouraged.

EDIT: added full test class (below) for the real CUT.

```
public final class ListObservingCacheTest
{
    @Mocked DummyTask mockTask;
    final int refreshIntervalMillis = 30;
    final List<Integer> initialItems = asList(1, 2);
    final List<Integer> newItemsAfterRefreshInterval = asList(3, 4, 5);

    @Before
    public void arrangeTaskOutputForMultipleCalls() {
        new Expectations() {{
            mockTask.acquireList();
            result = initialItems;
            result = newItemsAfterRefreshInterval;
        }};

        // A trick to avoid a long initial delay before the scheduled task is first
        // executed (a better solution might be to change the SUT to read the
        // initial delay from a system property).
        new MockUp<ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor>() {
            @Mock
            ScheduledFuture<?> scheduleAtFixedRate(
                Invocation inv,
                Runnable command, long initialDelay, long period, TimeUnit unit
            ) {
                return inv.proceed(command, 0, period, unit);
            }
        };
    }

    @After
    public void shutdownTheExecutorService() {
        ScheduledExecutorService executorService = 
            Deencapsulation.getField(ObservingCache.class, ScheduledExecutorService.class);
        executorService.shutdown();
    }

    @Test
    public void getTheInitialItemsImmediatellyAfterCreatingTheCache() throws Exception {
        // Arrange: empty, as there is nothing left to do beyond what the setup method
        // already does.

        // Act:
        ListObservingCache<Integer> obsCache = 
            new ListObservingCache<>(() -> mockTask.acquireList(), refreshIntervalMillis);
        List<Integer> items = obsCache.getItems();

        // Assert:
        assertEquals(initialItems, items);
    }

    @Test
    public void getTheSameItemsMultipleTimesBeforeTheCacheRefreshIntervalExpires() throws Exception {
        // Act:
        ListObservingCache<Integer> obsCache = 
            new ListObservingCache<>(() -> mockTask.acquireList(), refreshIntervalMillis);
        List<Integer> items1 = obsCache.getItems();
        List<Integer> items2 = obsCache.getItems();
        List<Integer> itemsIfTaskGotToBeCalledAgain = mockTask.acquireList();
        List<Integer> items3 = obsCache.getItems();

        // Assert:
        assertEquals(initialItems, items1);
        assertEquals(initialItems, items2);
        assertEquals(initialItems, items3);
        assertEquals(newItemsAfterRefreshInterval, itemsIfTaskGotToBeCalledAgain);
    }

    @Test
    public void getNewItemsAfterTheCacheRefreshIntervalExpires() throws Exception {
        // Act:
        ListObservingCache<Integer> obsCache = 
            new ListObservingCache<>(() -> mockTask.acquireList(), refreshIntervalMillis);
        List<Integer> items1 = obsCache.getItems();
        Thread.sleep(refreshIntervalMillis);
        List<Integer> items2 = obsCache.getItems();

        // Assert:
        assertEquals(initialItems, items1);
        assertEquals(newItemsAfterRefreshInterval, items2);
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, so how would you write this test instead?

Comment: I would write separate tests. Although, in this case it seems that the method being tested would just be executing the same code, only with different inputs; in this case I would simply execute it once, with whatever inputs.

Comment: In this case, there is a very good reason for recording 2 expectations and having 2 assertions.
I still think we're not understanding each other. I added the class under test for clarity, maybe this would help better understand the problem.
Basically, the ObservingCache is supposed to run a Callable task every 300 (or a different number of) milliseconds, and its getItems() method is supposed to return the result of that task, therefore calling it only once wouldn't test anything. ListObservingCache is an ObservingCache extension that returns a list.

Comment: I just noticed that the "trick" within the @Before method doesn't seem to work, as the original method is still getting called with an initial delay of 600000 (as hard coded in class ObservingCache, checked with debugger). The tests still pass though. It also seems to be the case in other places where I try using the Mockups API. What actually triggers the mocking of the methods under test? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

When new Expectations() is used in code, an instance of Expectations is created with providedInt value. So, though providedInt is changed in testRegisterInt(), state of Expectations instance does not change.  You can try setter to change the result of Expectations.

Ideally, there should not be any logic in stubs.  I would rather create multiple stubs in multiple test methods(if its really needed) or use anyInteger sort of stuff based on my needs.